# installation failed after renaming app folder

Tags: android

Because I had multiple versions of my android app I deleted a few old ones and renamed the folder with all the app data (the one in the folder where all the projects get stored). Then I opened my project again and as soon as I want to test my App on my device I get this error:

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File: D:\AndroidStudioProjekte\Assets 16.01.2017\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk.
```

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

There were no changes made to the code. Already tried to rename it back but that did not work...

Comment: Perform a `clean build`. Also, what do you mean by _I deleted a few old ones_, what exactly did you delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Hint 1: Go to the device's Settings->Apps, check if your app is showing in the list. I assume it is installed for some different profile not for your active profile. You need to uninstall it for all the profiles

Hint 2: File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Hint 3: It may be a problem with the ROM you are running. Install the required JB rom for your device(like OTA JB rom for my Nexus S)

Comment: as soon as I unchecked instant run it worked. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Doing a clean of the project and then a new make worked for me also.

In Android Studio this can be done as follows:

Build > Clean Project

Build > Make Project

This way you don't have to disable Instant Run. Hope it helps!